# Get a more Accurate search bar In Django

Tags: django, django-views

I currently have a working search bar for my Django website, but because of my database getting bigger the results get less accurate, for Example if I type in Her, the first object that shows up is The Marshall MatHERs LP2, but I want the Object that is literally named "her" to come first to make it more accurate, how to do this?

Code:

```
def search_album(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searched = request.POST.get('searched')
        album = Album.objects.filter(title__contains=searched)

        return render(request, 'home/search_album.html', {'searched':searched, 'album':album})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/search_album.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__exact` lookup in Django queries to get exact matches and then combine it with the other results.

```
exact_matches = Album.objects.filter(title__exact=searched)
containing_matches = Album.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)
results = list(exact_matches) + list(containing_matches)
```

Comment: Yes, but I still want to list out the objects only containing what is searched just later on.

Comment: The easiest way to do that, would be using two separate queries and then simply concatenating the results with the exact results taking precedence. The more complex way would be using tools such as Elastic Search which provide score-based searches.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the first way.